# Would it be beneficial to list a game I'm developing on my resume?

Tags: resume

I've been working on & off on a game for about a bit over a year in my spare time, and I'm trying to decide if it should go on my resume when applying for jobs. My thought was to show that I enjoy learning new things & being creative in my free time. However, the position is not in the games industry, but more of a general programming position.

My fear would be appearing distracted or otherwise not "devoted" to the position or company - I would do game development full time if I thought I could.

Comment: I should clarify that I have a full time job, and that this would be an extra detail rather than a major point

Comment: Is the game released yet? Or is it a project you've started and has yet to reach the market.

Comment: It is not released, but it's far enough along that I feel comfortable regularly showing updates/screenshots/videos to try and drum up interest. My hope would be to release this spring.

Comment: I don't know about how the rest of the world views hobby game developers, but in game development it's kind of meaningless until you have something to show off.  Otherwise the assumption is that you're one of the many who says they are making a game but hasn't actually made anything concrete yet... and may never do so.

Comment: Does the game in its current state demonstrate advanced skills in an area relevant to this job application? If so, maybe. If not, mentioning it serves no purpose and it can be dumped into the (usually not included)"hobbies and other interests" section.

Comment: In my personal experience, the gaming-based projects I've done have been far more complex than the real work-related projects I've done; but this might be an exception.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on the industry you're in, your personality, and that of the interviewer(s).

I would include it in the Other Interests section **only if** it is far enough along to reflect well on you.  As an interviewer, I really don't care about your plans or what you're going to do, **I care about what you've already done.**

A well polished game can show attention to detail, imagination, skill, and a willingness to stand out from all the drone resumes that make hiring manager's eyes glaze over.

In your specific case, you may want to leave it off the resume until it's been released and has been in use for a couple of months.  It needs to be fairly solid.  You don't want it to crash during an interview.

Comment: I agree, I have had good feedback from listing a game but mine was actually playable online and was a first of a kind.

Comment: "It depends". That's the important part. It depends wether the industry you're aiming at likes creativity. For a job in a software shop, it's probably a good idea. For a job in finance? No way! "Creative" and "banking" are two words that do not sound well together.

Comment: Part of the reason that I thought about doing this in the first place, is because a few of the jobs I'm applying for encourage you to list a GitHub account. While I do have an account, 99% of my work is locked away (on this game) in a private repo, rather than having made great contributions to the open source community.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against it, unless you're applying for a game developer position. I'd definitely not mention incomplete games (for reasons mentioned by @DanPichelman).

In my experience, certain interviewers might actually consider you infantile (regardless of your skills) if they see games listed on your resume.

I made several games in the past (and I have a fair bit of software engineering experience) but when I had my games listed as past projects, several interviewers asked me if I thought it was professional to appear among "such rabble" and wasting my time on "such worthless projects". Eventually I just removed them from my resume.

(These games were all developed by a team of 2-3 people, so they weren't single-person projects and all were completed at the time of these interviews.)

I personally think that (completed) game development experience is very useful and shows creativity and passion, it seems to be a gamble when it comes to "serious" interviewing.

**Edit**:  I don't want to give the impression that *every* interviewer was like this - I only remember these examples vividly exactly because of how surprising their questions were.

Comment: Wow. Those interviewers really know nothing about software development, and in particular, how hard it is to make a good game.

Comment: @l19 I agree with you - initially that's why I had my games listed. And I also don't want to give the impression that every interviewer was like this - I only remember these examples vividly exactly because of how surprising their questions were.